# Pyspark dataframe merge with indicator similar to pandas merge indicator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am using Python `pyspark.pandas`. I have two PySpark dataframes. I want to merge both dataframes and for that I am using `merge()` method of PySpark.

In my merged dataframe, I need one column indicating from which side data is combine i.e `left_only`, `right_only`, `both`. I did some research and came to know we have similar things in pandas , but not in PySpark.

When I am using below code snippet, my join is working fine. but in my final df `dfMerged` I need one extra column indicating `left`, `right`,  `both`.

```
 dfMerged = _left_df.merge(_right_df, how='left',left_on= ['Col1'], right_on=['Col1'], suffixes=('_L', '_R'))
```

In pandas we can use below code snippet but same code snippet is not working in PySpark. It's giving me error

```
dfMerged = _left_df.merge(_right_df, how='left',left_on= ['Col1'], right_on=['Col1'], suffixes=('_L', '_R'), indicator=  True)
```

Error:

> TypeError: DataFrame.merge() got an unexpected keyword argument 'indicator'